# The requested resource was not found on this server. django

Tags: python, django

[I have added my path into urlpatterns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTVtI.png)

[songs.urls file which was included in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTVtI.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHl9s.png)

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLkhE.png)

[error occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5k0f.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in urls.py
import songs views

```
from songs import views
```

in url patterns add

```
path('songs/',views.index),
```

directly include this in main url